# Get sent SMS delivery report

Tags: windows-phone

I would like to know if there is any API available to get the status of sent SMS programmatically that is SMS delivery report.

The code to send SMS is -

```
SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
smsComposeTask.To = destinationAddr;
smsComposeTask.Body = message;
smsComposeTask.Show();
```

Above code requires user interaction to send SMS. Once user sends SMS then I would like to get the delivery status of the SMS.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The only way to do that is to read messages to check for delivery report and the API to read SMS is strictly available to OEMs for security reasons.